# How do I access my js files in fortrabbit

Tags: ssh, laravel, laravel-4, http-status-code-403, fortrabbit

I just started using Fortrabbit to host the app we are working on. I am using Laravel 4. For some reason there are a select few .css fils and all of my .js files are not accessible. I am getting a 403 access forbidden error. How do I get around this. I have made sure the files are there, but for some reason I am unable to access them. I even tried running chmod 777 and 775 on my assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

Access forbidding errors usually relate to some kind of (overzealous) .htaccess rule. I'd recommend to open a ticket with the App name and URLs to the problematic files..